# how to embed an openstreetmap iframe in reveal.js

Tags: iframe, openstreetmap, reveal.js

I would like to embed `iframe` from openstreetmap in my reveal.js presentation by it doesn't work out of the box.
Any suggestion ?

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=5.124435424804688%2C45.05072537350321%2C5.890731811523438%2C45.322219956396964&amp;layer=mapnik&amp;marker=45.186634524469866%2C5.5075836181640625" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>
<br/>
<small><a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=45.1866&amp;mlon=5.5076#map=11/45.1866/5.5076">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

the result is an empty box

Comment: This works for me as expected. Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: My bad, today it works ! I don't understand what I misted !